# Forced oscillation in a pendulum and resonances

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, nonlinear-system

In a pendulum without the small angles approximation the equation describing the motion of the mass is:
$$\ddot{\phi}(t)=-\dfrac{g}{l}\sin\left(\phi(t)\right)$$
Applying a sinusoidal force 
$F(t)=A\sin(\omega t)$ to the mass $m$, the equation of the pendulum becomes:
$$\ddot{\phi}(t)=-\dfrac{g}{l}\sin\left(\phi(t)\right)-A\sin(\omega t)$$
Is there any analytical method to solve this equation in order to find the possible resonances? Thanks

Comment: Without external force, you may multiply the original equation by $\dot{\phi}(t)$ and then integrate it to get the first constant of integration. $H=(1/2)(\dot{\phi}(t))^2-(g/l)\cos(\phi(t))$. It can be solved with elliptical functions/integrals.

Comment: @mike: It's correct, but unfortunately I have an external force.

Comment: I would be flabbergasted if there was an exact analytical approach. What you should probably explore instead are various perturbative analyses, such as the method of multiple scales.